# Swift: what is a type signature with angle brackets and a comma

Tags: swift

In Alamofire, the type signature for the `request` method closure is:

> (Response<AnyObject, NSError>)

What does this mean?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See also the section  "Result Type" in the [Alamofire 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

Comment: The question I am duplicating discusses a signature of `<a: b>`, I am asking about `<a, b>`

Comment: `Result<AnyObject, NSError>` is a generic type with *two* type placeholders, like `Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value>` in the answer that I linked to.